# Fail2ban trigger on network rather than ip address

Tags: fail2ban

I'm using fail2ban to protect an ssh daemon, but I'm seeing something that fail2ban doesn't seem to trigger on by default. In my fail2ban logs I see entries like the following:

```
2020-03-09 17:29:41,774 fail2ban.filter         [19104]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.1.1.22 - 2020-03-09 17:29:41
2020-03-09 17:29:57,696 fail2ban.filter         [19104]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.1.1.25 - 2020-03-09 17:29:57
2020-03-09 17:30:32,714 fail2ban.filter         [19104]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.1.1.59 - 2020-03-09 17:30:32
2020-03-09 17:30:48,414 fail2ban.filter         [19104]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.1.1.90 - 2020-03-09 17:30:48
2020-03-09 17:31:07,640 fail2ban.filter         [19104]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.1.1.11 - 2020-03-09 17:31:07
2020-03-09 17:31:12,941 fail2ban.filter         [19104]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.1.1.22 - 2020-03-09 17:31:12
2020-03-09 17:31:17,717 fail2ban.filter         [19104]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.1.1.32 - 2020-03-09 17:31:17
2020-03-09 17:31:22,713 fail2ban.filter         [19104]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.1.1.59 - 2020-03-09 17:31:22
2020-03-09 17:31:24,581 fail2ban.filter         [19104]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.1.1.90 - 2020-03-09 17:31:24
```

This pattern will repeat in about 8 hours, along with a few more patterns from the same /24. Since these connection attempts are all coming from the same network I consider this to all be from the same attacker and would like to block the whole /24. I found some instructions on how to block a network rather than a host on the Debian Bugs mailing list [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=724274), and that works great, but can't find how to trigger on a /24 pattern rather than an individual ip address. I could make my rules a bit more restrictive (trigger on two failures, possibly) to catch this instance, but it wouldn't catch all of the instances I'm seeing in my logs.

Any pointers to setting this up?

Comment: Yep, searching for the same at the moment. In your logs it's about one request each 10 seconds. So I would love to see a way to recognize if 32 request per 5 Minutes from the same network arrive, block it for an hour).